# Смена bacground-image в слайдах owl-carousel при смене слайда

Tags: javascript, html, css3, owl-carousel

Здраствуйте, мой вопрос вот в чем: у мнея есть слайдер, в нем есть 3 слайда, мне нужно чтобы, при смене слайда, у него менялся background-image ( пропадал, и появлялся новый )

Comment: Дайте пример, так ничего непонятно.

Comment: если зайти на сайт к owl-carousel, то по ссылке на их репо =>[ТЫК](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html)<= можно найти:
- готовые примеры
- готовые либы для анимаций

Comment: Первый пример по этой ссылке - как раз то что нужно.